# Partial sum estimate for $\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p^{1/2}}$

Tags: number-theory, analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, summation-method

Forgive my question if its elementary, I'm very new in number theory.

We know from Merten's theorem

$$\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p} = \ln \ln x + B + O\left(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right)$$

Here $B= \sum_p \left(\ln(1-1/p)+1/p\right)$

My question is how to get similar estimate for :

$$\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p^{1/2}}$$

Comment: You may find this paper interesting: https://doi.org/10.1007/s11139-016-9847-4

Comment: @Gary thank you for comment I now reading it.

Comment: You need the PNT, the Mertens theorem (through a partial summation) gives the asymptotic of $\sum_{p\le x}\frac1{p^s}$ for any $s> 1$ but it isn't enough for $s\in (0,1)$. @Gary

Comment: @renus thank you for commenting. How would you deal with such problems then?

Comment: What do you mean? From the PNT a partial summation (to make $\pi(m)$ appear) will give your asymptotic.

Comment: @GSA_1 The point is that Merten's theorem does not require the knowledge of the (non-trivial) prime number theorem. It can be proved using fairly elementary tools. However, to deal with the problem you posed, the use of the PNT is inevitable.

Comment: @Gary again thank you, could you provide me with the reference for that? Or answer in that direction?

Comment: Mertens' result can be proved by first showing that $
\sum\limits_{p \le x} {\frac{{\log p}}{p}}  = \log x + O(1)
$ using elementary arguments, and then using partial summation. If you try to approach your sum with the same method, you will observe that one needs a more precise estimate than just $O(1)$ in the above formula. Such a more precise estimate cannot be achived without the PNT. Without PNT, the only thing you can show is that $$
\sum\limits_{p \le x} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt p }}}  = O\!\left( {\frac{{\sqrt x }}{{\log x}}} \right).
$$

Comment: @Gary again thank you. Could you Please mention the case with pnt? If you answer it I will accept as a answer!

Comment: It is the case $k=-1/2$ in the paper, see Section 2. I shall not repeat their proof here.